# PRNG to generate a known set of values

Tags: random

Say I want the first N numbers generated by PRNG to be some list `[n1, n2, n3, n1, nx...]`. Is there any way to accomplish this (basically find the appropriate seed for the PRNG?) in some efficient manor, short of bruteforcing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point? If you have a random number generator `g`, you can write your own random number generator `h` that returns `n1,n2,...` for the first `N` calls and thereafter returns the same as `g`.

But to answer your question: if the PRNG is any good, then you will have to brute-force it, which will be impractical if `N` is more than about four or five.